# How to use external IP internally and using it with ownCloud? And WAMP shutdown

Tags: ip, wamp, external, owncloud

I have setup a server on of my PCs and I am running ownCloud on it. Everything is working fine but I wanted to ask a few things just to make the whole process more convenient.

- How can I use a dynamic IP address in ownCloud? I have a ddns but, since I have a dyn external IP address, I need to put in the ddns again and modify the account when the IP changes. Is there a way through which ownCloud could work on the ddns and not on external IP address? (I hope you got what I meant) **IMAGE:** http://s27.postimg.org/r0224wfsz/Untitled_2.jpg
- Also, is there a way to use the ddns(xyzz.co) in the same home network in which my server is? instead of the internal IP address(192.168.1.2). Because again, I need to modify the account when I am in the home network and when outside.
- My WAMP server shuts down automatically like it would if I manually exit it. Is there a solution to that too? I have kept it on auto start on OS boot-up. But, I think that is not the solution.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Why not let your router attached to your server cope with this? In the most recent routers, you can set your (D)DNS-settings.
2. You can set port mapping in your router to an external address. Then, when you are at home, you don't need to edit the settings of the sync client since you can always use your external IP-address.
3. I'd use `cron` for that. Look it up when you enter `crontab --help` in the terminal. On most distributions, cron comes with examples in the cron itself. So you can just edit it by entering `crontab -e`. [Enough online, too](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Comment: Hey thanks for replying!

1. I have a d-link router, so they only have option for dyndns.com, for which I will need to pay. Currently I am using ddns.net.

2. You cannot open servers with the external IP in the same network. Like, if I have a server is at 192.168.1.100:81, and if my external IP address is 177.123.123.444, then I will not be able to open the server by typing 177.123.123.444:81 in the same network. I will have to enter 192.168.1.100:81

3. I hadn't heard about cron. I think that will solve this problem. But, can I change wamp settings, instead?

Let me know if I am wrong.
Thanks

Comment: 1. Too bad :) 2. Don't forget to define the port number on your external address. Internal 1.1.1.1:81 might point to external 2.2.2.2:8080. 3. I don't think changing is an option. Cron is great! Please mark as answer when it does :D

Comment: 1. The problem is not with assigning ddns to the router. For that I have an auto-update client by no-ip.com. 2. Of course, I have assigned the same port to external and internal IP but, you cannot access your external IP from the same network, whats the soln? Like, extrnl IP-117.117.117:8001 cant be opened from the same network!! 3. Since I am hosting it on windows, theres feature called scheduled tasks. I have added one to start WAMP within every 1 hr. I think it is working fine till now. I didnt get what you said about marking the answer. I hope you understood the second point. Try doing it.